# Project folder is taken as controller in zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am setting a demo Zend project on a windows server.
That is having base url like http://example.com/JPZend/public/

But on some url like http://example.com/JPZend/public/user/index?page=2
it gives the following page not found error where http://example.com/JPZend/public/user runs perfectly.

Page not found
Exception information:
Message: Invalid controller specified (JPZend) 
Request Parameters:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'JPZend',
  'action' => 'public',
  'user' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
  'page' => '2',
)
```

What am I missing? Seems like some virtual hosting issue?

Comment: do you have any Zend routes configured for this project?

Comment: @alex No, I haven't configured them.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you use the **public** folder as your **webroot**.

So your URL would look like this: **http://example.com/JPZend**

The default route in ZF is:

```
:controller/:action

Or with Modules enabled:

:module/:controller/:action
```

To tell ZF that you have another Base URL, you need to add a line to you **application.ini**:

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = /JPZend/public
```

And to your **.htaccess** or similar under windows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /JPZend/public
```

Have fun!

Comment: I am using Windows Server so have to use something for web.config. But I'll try it out. Thanks :)